# Creating unsigned ClickOnce deployments with MageUI

Tags: deployment, clickonce

With .Net 3.5 SP1 it is no longer required to sign ClickOnce manifest files.  We've incorporated MageUI into our deployment process and would like to deploy some unsigned applications.  Mage will let me create an unsigned application manifest.  However, it will *not* let me point the deployment manifest to the unsigned application manifest.  It says, "The application manifest is not signed".

Is this a bug?  I'm running version 3.5.30729.1; is there a newer version that fixes this?  Any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good work-around?

Comment: No.  I was just toying with the idea of removing the signature from our deployments, but quite pursuing it after this roadblock.  If you ever find a good solution, please post it.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.

Workaround is to add the XML Fragment by hand into the Application Manifest XML

Answer (score 2):

Just a word of warning -- are you deploying this internally-only? Removing the signing is allowed, but not advised. It removes all hashing of the files, and makes your application vulnerable to having the files replaced by malware.

Answer (score 0):

What XML Fragment needs to go into the Application Manifest XML to create unsigned deployment manifests?

Answer (score -2):

Try .Net Frame work 4.0

Comment: why?  What feature in 4.0 makes clickonce easier in build processes?  or are you referring to something in VS2010?